# What is the proper way of removing a deployment from kubernetes cleanly

Tags: kubernetes

I have an example deployment running on a kubernetes cluster that also exposes a service and has a persistent volume bound by persistent volume claim.

I would expect that running:

```
kubectl delete deployment 'deployment_name'
```

Will delete everything but after running the above the service and storage still exist and I still have to manually delete the service and the persistent volume for the persistent volume claim to release.

Isn't there a single command to remove everything cleanly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are creating deployment, service and PV in 3 separate YAML files you will have to remove them one by one.

However if you have 3 of them in the same YAML file, you can delete all three at once by applying:

```
kubectl delete -f file.yaml
```

Comment: You can also use a directory path - https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/19767

Answer (score 1):

If you have defined deployment, pv, pvc and service in a single file say `file.yaml`, then you can delete all of them using single command:

```
kubectl delete -f file.yaml
```

This will delete all the objects defined in that yaml file.